# Reload UITableViewCell without UITableView scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using a `UISegmentedControl` which changes the contents of a `UITableViewCell`.  After the segment changes I need to reload the cell to update the height of it.  I do this by calling:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.segmentIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

However, this makes the `UITableView` scroll to the top.  What is the best way to do this without having the table scroll?

Comment: That line of code will not make the table view scroll. You must be doing something else that makes the table view scroll back to the top.

Comment: @rmaddy that could easily be the case.  I'm new to this code base and there is a lot going on in the UITableView.  Anything specific I can be on the lookout for that would cause the scroll to the top?

Comment: Look for calls to `reloadData` or any call that explicitly scrolls the table view. Remember that `UITableView` extends `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I put in some break points and noticed ```cellForRowAtIndexPath``` is called once, but ```heightForRowAtIndexPath``` is called multiple times after the segment is changed.  Could this be the problem?   Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: That's fine and doesn't affect scrolling.

Comment: why dont you place a button on top of tableview and use it for reloading the tableview ?

Comment: @Mr.T I don't want to sacrifice design.  If I use a constant height for the cell in ```heightForRowAtIndexPath``` the table view no longer scrolls to the top.  Maybe it has to do with a dramatic change in cell height?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `[self.tableView visibleCells]` and then find this cell and change

Comment: The OP already has the index path for the one row that needs reloading and the OP shows that one line of code to reload just the one row.

Comment: No problem. You can either delete the answer or update it as needed.